# button click on jquery dialog having issues after ajax call

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4, modal-dialog

My modal window(jquery) has one link and two buttons. On click of the link I am replacing the current view with a new view using ajax call.  The new view has two button `Continue`(btnContinue) and `Cancel`. 
The problem I am facing is the button click on the newly loaded view would not work.

My code :

```
       $(".ddlCart li").click(function (e) {

        var ddlselectedVal = $(this).attr('id');
        var agentId = $("#AgentId").val();

        var EnvironmentURL = $("#EnvironmentURL").val();

        var Action = "PreAddToCart"

        var postData = {
            AgentId: agentId,
            ActionTypeValue: Action
        };

        var close = function (event, ui) {
            $(this).dialog("destroy");
        }
        var open = function (event, ui) {
            var agentId = $("#AgentId").val();
            var url = EnvironmentURL + "/Stats/SearchContacts";

            $("#btncart_cancel").on("click", function () {
               $('#dvModalDialog').dialog("close");
            });


     $("#lnkCreateNewcart").on("click", function () {

                            var url = EnvironmentURL + "/MLSReports/Stats/Cart";
                            //Send the data using post and put the results in a div                   
                            $.post(url, {
                               ActionTypeValue: "CreateNewContact"
                            },
                                function (data) {
                                  // Replace current data with data from the ajax call to the div.         
                                    $("#dvModalDialog").empty().append(data);

                                });
                        }); 


//******* This is not firing ....
     $("#btnContinue").on("click", function () {
                            alert('This click is from the second View');
                        });      


        };

        var rd = Mod.ReportsDialog({
            title: 'Add To Cart',
            close: close,
            open: open
        });
        rd.url = EnvironmentURL + "/Stats/Cart";
        rd.targetElement = '#dvModalDialog'
        rd.formName = '#frmCart'
        rd.postData = postData
        rd.open();
        var $that = this;
        });
```

Comment: Try binding your 2 buttons outside the first click handler, perhaps?

Comment: Did you tried to rebind events for your fresh component ? When you're generating the new view in ajax, you have to bind ( with $('#idNewComponent').on(...) ) your new components.

Comment: I tried binding outside the first click handler Still didn't work.

Comment: Check the id of the button is it the same? check your console also. Try moving that function inside the second view instead of first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** 1

Let me know if this works:

```
$(document).on('click', '#btnContinue', function(e) {
```

instead of:

```
$("#btnContinue").click(function (e) {
```

Comment: what would the code be if the button is type="submit"

Comment: See if this works: $(document).on('click', '#btnContinue input[type=submit]', function(e) {

Comment: What are you submitting? Try this: $(document).on('submit', '#btnContinue input[type=submit]', function(e) {

Comment: I need to validate the form.

Comment: `I need to validate the form. Tried this but not working.  $(document).on('click', '#btnContinue , function (e) {             $("#formCreateContact").validate({                             rules: {        Contact_FirstName: {  
                required: true
        }
                           }
                                                   });

Answer (score 0):

Instead of :

```
     $(".ddlCart li").click(function (e) {
...
```

use this:

```
$(".ddlCart li").on('click', function(e){
```

..

Because the first function only binds to the existing html elements on the page and doesn't recognize the new ones.

Comment: do you have the class that you are calling in the new element ?